# Wordpress login screen not appearing after launch in microsoft azure

Tags: microsoft

I just launched a wordpress instance on azure but when I go to the URL, I get the following:

> This web app has been successfully created
>
> There's nothing here yet, but Microsoft Azure makes it simple to
>   publish content with GIT, FTP or your favorite development tool such
>   as Visual Studio, Visual Studio Online or WebMatrix

I tried http://drone1.azurewebsites.net/wp-admin but no joy.

I did this about a year previously and had no issues but not this time. Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

Looking at:

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/documentation/articles/web-sites-php-web-site-gallery/

I don't see any instance of MySQL in my window.

I believe it is meant to start automatically.  Any idea what I have done wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In azure there is a bitnami wordpress instance.

[image]

I used the bitnami instance and the worpress login appeared as expected.

I think you must launch a MySQL instance separately to use the wordpress but the bitnami instance works simply and is good enough for me.